# Por que Math.round(-0.2) devolve "-0" e não "0"

Tags: javascript

Eu tive um problema com o Javascript hoje que vou descrever:

Eu tenho uma coleção de valores, por exemplo:

```
US         11.3123
Brazil     -0.2291
UK          0.4501
```

Eu quero mostrar os valores sem as casas decimais, arredondando, e o resultado é esse:

```
US         11
Brazil     -0
UK          0
```

O problema é que "Brazil" está com o valor "-0" ao invés de "0".

Eu até posso corrigir facilmente:

```
html += '<tr><td>' + arr[i].Country + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + d3.format(arr[i].Value || 0)) + '</td></tr>';
```

**Mas, por que o Javascript mostra o valor com sinal de negativo?**

---

**Atualização**

Estou usando o d3, e ele está transmitindo o comportamento do Javascript ao invés de devolver o 0 sem sinal como o JS puro faz.

Mas a minha pergunta ainda continua, porque no console eu digito Math.round(-0.02) e é devolvido -0.

Comment: Tem certeza que não tem mais coisa ai pelo meio? Os meus testes devolveram sempre "0" e não "-0".

Comment: @Filipe Que browser você está usando? No Chrome, ao imprimir `Math.round(-0.2)` no console obtive `-0`.

Comment: Utilizei o chrome

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso não é uma característica somente de JavaScript, mas sim da forma como o **ponto flutuante** funciona. Nessa representação, [existem dois valores para o zero](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_flutuante#Valores_Especiais): `+0` e `-0`. As implementações são obrigadas a tratá-los como iguais (em comparações), mas ainda são representados por dois valores diferentes.

Se sua aplicação não se interessa pelos dois valores (como de fato, na maior parte dos domínios só interessa um zero) então sua forma de corrigí-lo (fazendo "ou" com zero) está ok. Só tome cuidado com o `NaN` (*not a number*), pois ele também será convertido para zero segundo essa lógica.

Comment: muito obrigado pela explicação e pelo lembrete do `NaN`! ( na verdade antes do array, tem um tratamento de `null`, `NaN` e string vazias para "0" - faz parte da especificação do programa :)).